# How to incorporate FANN with other C libraries?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, signature

I am using FANN, pyfann in particular, for signature recognition. Before I can use AI, I have to prepocess the image first using the imagelab, a compilation of image processing libraries like image.h,jpegio.h,etc. My problem is I don't know how to incorporate the two so that I can use the their libraries in just one program. I have to extract the signatures' features like no. of pixels and length and width, but I don't know how to input these data to FANN. Any help? I really don't know exactly where to start.